# All Images Become White after visiting PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm creating my Android application and faced this peculiar issue.
None of my teammates have experienced this before and I'm stuck with this for days now.

So what happens is that after going to Setting Fragment and coming back, ALL images (both ImageView and Facebook SimpleDraweeView) become white.

If you see pictures below, you may see how all images change to white.

This always occur if I tap the Setting tab (the last one on the right) and coming back to any tab.

[image: Normal View]

[image: After Error]

This line of my Setting Fragment is what makes the problem.

```
childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings_container, MainSettingsFragment()).commit()
```

If I comment this line out, then everything is fine. The problem is, the line below doesn't cause any problem. While the above line is for the fragment, the below line is for activity.

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.msettings_container, MainSettingsFragment()).commit()
```

The below is the code block of fragment lifecycle.

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        profile_profileimage.setOnClickListener {
            val imageList = arrayListOf(MainActivity.myProfile)
            val overlay = ImageOverlayView(requireContext())
            ImageViewer.Builder(requireContext(), imageList)
                .hideStatusBar(false)
                .allowZooming(true)
                .allowSwipeToDismiss(true)
                .setOverlayView(overlay)
                .setImageChangeListener { position ->
                    overlay.setImageUrl(MainActivity.myProfile)
                }
                .show()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        refreshMemorials()
        loadProfile()
    }

    private fun loadProfile() {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            ...
            profile_profileimage.setImageURI(MainActivity.myProfile)
            ...
        }
    }
```

This is the XML code for profile_profileimage

```xml
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/profile_profileimage"
    app:actualImageScaleType="fitXY"
    app:roundAsCircle="true"
    app:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
    app:roundingBorderColor="@android:color/white" />
```

But, I want to have Settings as one of fragment.

I can't see what is going wrong here. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: looks like they all reset to default , see the instagram icon dosent change

Comment: @Anshul what do you mean? I can't find any source with "instagram icon doesnt change" in Google.

Comment: Add the code block where you are setting the Image including calling method of lifecycle .

Comment: Bellow your user image(large one) there is an static Instagram icon , which on layout updates dosent change because its static , hence according to me when your layout updates your all images reset to default , because your helper function(one which toggle images) isint called on layout updates.

Comment: @ADM I did add the code block with fragment lifecycle and the all codes that touches profile_profileimage. It is the top image displaying the profile image of user.

Comment: @Anshul It's actually tint that's assigned to all images when I go to Settings and go back to other tab. I have no idea why tint color of white is assigned since no such attribute I did give in xml. Somehow, tint color is assigned... Do you think that this may be due to themes?